# In Bash, what is file descriptor 255 for, can I use it?

Tags: bash, file-descriptors

I understand **file descriptor** (or file handler) is an **file IO technique** in Linux systems.

I also know that each process has 3 standard streams (namely stdin, stdout and stderr) that are represented by files with descriptors from 0 to 3.

However, I notice that all the processes I examined with `lsof -p <pid>` has an extra file descriptor `255` with read permission.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729906/what-is-the-use-of-file-descriptor-255-in-bash-process), I learned that this feature is specific to *Bash shell*, however both the answer the and the referenced source didn't really explain what this file descriptor is for.

My question:

1. What is the 255 file descriptor for?
2. Can I make use of it in my Bash script or is it just an internal working mechanism that is not supposed to be used/manipulated manually?

Comment: In my opinion your questions were answered on the linked page.

Comment: I will examine the answer again to see if it answers my question. I only noticed now that you are the one who gave that answer ;)

Comment: @Cyrus saying that "it's a little trick" without explaining what that "little trick" is is not a proper answer.

Comment: The first comment on the linked answer seems to have a better discussion... [The last reply](https://lists.gt.net/linux/kernel/9748#9748) is probably what you are looking for...

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/866722/772601

Comment: Cyrus did not say that it was a "little trick", mosvy.  Xe quoted [Steve Parker](https://steve-parker.org/) saying that.  (-:

Comment: The standard descriptors are 0 to 2. 0 to 3 would be 4 descriptors.

Comment: @RubberStamp actually it's the [first reply](https://lists.gt.net/linux/kernel/9696#9696) in that discussion. The last one refers to a different situation -- when `bash` is run as `bash scriptfile`, and in that case `/proc/fd/255` will be a symlink to `scriptfile`.

Comment: @RubberStamp and that last comment is also plain wrong, because `bash` immediately closes the original script fd after dup'ing to a higher fd. And it doesn't do any dup'ing when the script is read from stdin; eg. `echo 'ls -l /proc/$$/fd' | bash`.

Answer (score 19):

For the last part of your question:

#### can I use it?

From `man bash`:

> Redirections  using file descriptors greater than 9 should be used with care, as they may conflict with file descriptors the shell uses internally.

So, if you mean use as creating a new fd with that number the answer is no.

If you mean use as: "write to that fd":

```
$ echo hello >/dev/fd/255"
```

Or to read from it:

```
$ read a </dev/fd/255
abc
$ echo "$a"
abc
```

the answer is yes.
But, probably, it should be better (independent of shell) to use `/dev/tty` to access the `tty`.

#### what is file descriptor 255 for?

As an alternative connection to the tty in case fd 1 (`/dev/stdout`) and fd 0 (`/dev/stdin`) get blocked.

[More detail](https://askubuntu.com/a/866722/772601).

Other shells may use a different number (like 10 in zsh)

```
$ zsh
mail% ls -l /proc/self/fd /proc/$$/fd/* &
[1] 3345
mail% lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Oct 14 09:46 /proc/3250/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Oct 14 09:50 /proc/3250/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Oct 14 09:50 /proc/3250/fd/10 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Oct 14 09:50 /proc/3250/fd/2 -> /dev/pts/2

/proc/self/fd:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Oct 14 09:50 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Oct 14 09:50 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Oct 14 09:50 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lr-x------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Oct 14 09:50 3 -> /proc/3345/fd

[1]  + done       ls -l /proc/self/fd /proc/$$/fd/*
mail%
```

From [mail list](https://lists.gt.net/linux/kernel/9748#9748):

> Fd 255 is used internally as a connection to the tty, so that it doesn't
> interfere with the use of exec to relocate fds. Bash also allocates high
> fds when handling a process substitution `<(foo)', for the same reason.
> Andreas Schwab

Comment: fd 255 is **not** used to "keep a copy of fd 1 and fd 0" -- you can easily verify that with `dd bs=1 | bash -i -c 'sleep .1; ls -l /proc/$$/fd' 2>/tmp/err | tee /tmp/out`. Also, that comment from the mailing list is about when `bash` is run as `bash scriptfile` (`255` being in that case the open handle to `scriptfile` -- and in that case, `ls -l /proc/pid/fd` will print very convincingly `255 -> scriptfile` ;-)), not about when it's run interactively.

Comment: I'm sorry that the source code snippets and analysis from my answer didn't convince you, but just to be clear: a) it's not an "alternative" connection to the tty, but the main connection to the tty, used for all tty related purposes b) it's copied from fd 2 (stderr) or opened directly from `/dev/tty`, not from fd 0 or fd 1 c) if fds 0, 1 or 2 get "blocked", bash will **not** use that 255 fd as an alternative for reading input from the user or for writing command output, prompts, error messages, etc.

Answer (score 16):

That `255` file descriptor is an open handle to the controlling tty and is only used when `bash` is run in interactive mode.

It allows you to redirect the `stderr` in the main shell, while still allowing the job control to function (ie. be able to kill processes with ^C, interrupt them with ^Z, etc).

Example:

```
$ exec 2> >(tee /tmp/err); ls /nosuchfile; sleep 1000
```

If you try that in a shell like `ksh93`, which is simply using file descriptor 2 as a reference to the controlling terminal, the `sleep` process will become immune to ^C and ^Z, and will have to be killed from another window/session. That's because the shell will not be able to set the process group of `sleep` as the foreground one in the terminal with `tcsetgrp()`, since file descriptor 2 no longer points to the terminal.

This is not `bash` specific, it's also used in `dash` and `zsh`, only that the descriptor is not moved that high (it's usually 10).

`zsh` will also use that fd to echo prompts and user input, so simply the following will work:

```
$ exec 2>/tmp/err
$
```

It has nothing to do with the file handles `bash` is using when reading scripts and setting up pipes (which are also dup'ed out of the way with the same function -- `move_to_high_fd()`), as it was suggested in other answers and comments.

`bash` is using such a large number in order to allow fds larger than `9` to be used with in-shell redirections (eg. `exec 87<filename`); that's not supported in other shells.

You can use that file handle yourself, but there's little point in doing so, because you can get a handle to the very **same** controlling terminal in any command with `... < /dev/tty`.

**Source code analysis of bash**:

In `bash`, the file descriptor of the controlling terminal is stored in the `shell_tty` variable. If the shell is interactive, that variable is initialized (at startup or after a failed exec) in `jobs.c:initialize_job_control()` by dup'ing it from `stderr` (if `stderr` is attached to a terminal) or by directly opening `/dev/tty`, and is then dup'ed again to a higher fd with `general.c:move_to_high_fd()`:

```
int
initialize_job_control (force)
     int force;
{
  ...
  if (interactive == 0 && force == 0)
    {
      ...
    }
  else
    {
      shell_tty = -1;

      /* If forced_interactive is set, we skip the normal check that stderr
         is attached to a tty, so we need to check here.  If it's not, we
         need to see whether we have a controlling tty by opening /dev/tty,
         since trying to use job control tty pgrp manipulations on a non-tty
         is going to fail. */
      if (forced_interactive && isatty (fileno (stderr)) == 0)
        shell_tty = open ("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK);

      /* Get our controlling terminal.  If job_control is set, or
         interactive is set, then this is an interactive shell no
         matter where fd 2 is directed. */
      if (shell_tty == -1)
        shell_tty = dup (fileno (stderr));        /* fd 2 */

      if (shell_tty != -1)
        shell_tty = move_to_high_fd (shell_tty, 1, -1);
      ...
    }
```

If `shell_tty` is not already the controlling tty, then it is made so:

```
          /* If (and only if) we just set our process group to our pid,
             thereby becoming a process group leader, and the terminal
             is not in the same process group as our (new) process group,
             then set the terminal's process group to our (new) process
             group.  If that fails, set our process group back to what it
             was originally (so we can still read from the terminal) and
             turn off job control.  */
          if (shell_pgrp != original_pgrp && shell_pgrp != terminal_pgrp)
            {
              if (give_terminal_to (shell_pgrp, 0) < 0)
```

`shell_tty` is then used to

1. get and set the foreground process group with `tc[sg]etpgrp` in `jobs.c:maybe_give_terminal_to()`, `jobs.c:set_job_control()` and `jobs.c:give_terminal_to()`
2. get and set the `termios(3)` params in `jobs.c:get_tty_state()` and `jobs.c:set_tty_state()`
3. get the terminal window size with `ioctl(TIOCGWINSZ)` in `lib/sh/winsize.c:get_new_window_size()`.

`move_to_high_fd()` is generally used with all the temporary file descriptors used by `bash` (script files, pipes, etc), thence the confusion in most comments that appear prominently in google searches.

The file descriptors used internally by `bash`, including `shell_tty` are all set to close-on-exec, so they won't be leaked to commands.