# How to make chrome run with proxy properly?

Tags: debian, chrome, socks5-proxy

I want to set my Chrome with socks5 proxy.

```
chrome://linux-proxy-config/
```

To input the `chrome://linux-proxy-config/` in Chrome, I'm presented with a page with this content:

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see man `google-chrome` for more information on flags and environment variables.

I input the command in console:

```
google-chrome-stable  --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080
```

Two effects for the above command:

- effect1: I can go surfing now via socks5 proxy.
- effect2: So many warnings info:

  ```
  "Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
  [3873:3960:0808/102301.399211:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(619)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
  [7:13:0808/102302.782729:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(107)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Shared memory region is not valid
  [3873:4069:0808/102302.788747:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(619)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
  [3873:4069:0808/102302.789045:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(619)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.UPower.GetDisplayDevice: object_path= /org/freedesktop/UPower: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
  ```

I want to fix effect2, that is to say, make the command run in background silently.

```
google-chrome-stable  --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080  &
```

Effect2 still exist, it can't run in background, warning info still pop out in the console.

Try other way:

```
sudo gvim /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
#replace the  `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito` with 
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable  --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

Run Chrome with its logo, Chrome can open, now I can't go surfing  with the proxy `socks5://127.0.0.1:1080`. How to fix it?

Comment: try run it with this:

`--proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND , EXCLUDE 127.0.0.1"`

Comment: Not a real answer, since I cannot test these suggestions; but 1) In `google-chrome.desktop` you likely have more than one `Exec` line; the one that takes effect when you start Chrome—and that you should try editing—is that in the `[Desktop Entry]` section, while the one you edited (with the `--incognito` option) likely is in the `[Desktop Action new-private-window]` section and only takes effect when you select the `New Incognito Window` entry from a context menu. 2) To silence a background job you may just redirect its output, e.g. `google-chrome-stable --proxy... 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &`.

Comment: @fra-san,please write it as a formal answer,it is tested ,feasible,i give you the 300 points.

Comment: @fra-san - Now I see your comment. It runs along the same line as my answer...

Comment: @it_is_a_literature - Do you feel your question was not fully addressed? It has been answered by *drawing from credible and/or official sources*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you found a way to make things work, and your only concern is getting too many warnings, you may do things your way discarding the messages:

```
<your command> 2> /dev/null
```

You would be [redirecting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-i-o-redirection) [file descriptor (FD)](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/f/file-descriptor.htm) #2, which is stderr, to a "black hole".
You may also want to discard messages sent to stdout (FD #1), although this is less common in cases like yours.
You have to check how much clutter you get.
So, you would have (redirecting only stderr):

```
google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080" 2> /dev/null &
```

or (redirecting stderr and stdout; these are alternative forms of the same command)

```
google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080" 2> /dev/null 1>&2 &
google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The syntax `2>&1` means redirecting FD #2 to wherever FD #1 goes.
The default FD is #1, so `>` is equivalent to `1>`.

---

For the rare cases you need more info than above, or for the sake of curiosity:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms

[In Bash, what is file descriptor 255 for, can I use it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475389/in-bash-what-is-file-descriptor-255-for-can-i-use-it)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, your attempt at editing `google-chrome.desktop` didn't work because that file has more than one `Exec` entry, and the one you changed wasn't the one that is actually used.

Using the [Chrome package for Debian](https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb) from Google's repository, `google-chrome.desktop` shows three `Exec` entries in three distinct sections (groups, in [freedesktop.org's nomenclature](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.1.html)):

```
$ grep -E '^Exec|^\[|^Name=' /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Google Chrome
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=New Incognito Window
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito
```

The one with the `--incognito` option—likely the one you edited—is only executed when you select "New Incognito Window" from a context menu (e.g. after right clicking on Chrome's icon in GNOME Activities).

Unless your goal was to change the configuration for every user on your system, I suggest you to create your own, customized version of `google-chrome.desktop`:

```
$ cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

And then edit the `Exec` entry, *at least* in the `[Desktop Entry]` group (you may want to keep the other `Exec` entries aligned to ensure Chrome will behave the same way no matter what menu entry you used to start it):

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks5://proxyURL:proxyPORT" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND , EXCLUDE proxyURL" %U
```

As noted by [Dominik Matis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/365319/dominik-matis) in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534472/how-to-make-chrome-run-with-proxy-properly#comment990868_534472), you may want to add the `--host-resolver-rules` option to prevent Chrome's DNS prefetcher from circumventing your proxy settings, as explained in the [Chromium documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/socks-proxy).

Adjust `proxyURL` and `proxyPORT` as needed; don't forget to set `proxyURL` for both the `--proxy-server` and `--host-resolver-rules` options.

If you want the default opening action to run Chrome without setting any proxy, you may leave the main `[Desktop Entry]`'s `Exec` entry untouched and add an [action](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/1.1/ar01s10.html) instead. It requires you to

1. add a name for a new action to the `Actions` key in the `[Desktop Entry]` group;
2. add a new action group.

```
[Desktop Entry]
...
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;new-proxied-window;

...

[Desktop Action new-proxied-window]
Name=New Proxied Window
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks5://proxyURL:proxyPORT" --host-resolver-rules="MAP * ~NOTFOUND , EXCLUDE proxyURL" %U
```

"New Proxied Window" will then appear as an option when you right click on Chrome's icon (it may require a logout/login). Note that all the concurrently running instances of Chrome will share the same proxy settings of the first one you opened, unless you start them with the `--user-data-dir` [option](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote about [the various ways Google Chrome is affected by proxy settings](https://hanxue-it.blogspot.com/2019/08/comprehensive-guide-for-proxy-settings.html). Rather than setting the proxy within Chrome, use the OS' settings instead.

If you are using GNOME, try using `gsettings`

```
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http host "myproxy.server.com"
gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.http port "3128"
```

Can you download a file from the Internet using `wget` or `curl`? Does the following command create an `index.html` file from Google's homepage?

```
wget https://www.google.com
```

If your problem is connecting to the SOCKS proxy and it is affecting other applications, try using [proxychains](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) or [pacproxy](https://github.com/williambailey/pacproxy).

```
$ proxychains4 google-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

cat   /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Google Chrome
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/google-chrome.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"  2> /dev/null 1>&2 &
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting Chrome's output in your desktop file? Are you seeing messages from Chrome somewhere when you start it by clicking on its icon? (Redirection should have a visible effect when you start Chrome from the command line only).