# In shell, when I run process in background, how can I get the "[job number] [PID]", redirected to a file?

Tags: shell, command-line, io-redirection

I want to redirect the output of this command `firefox &`. I know that adding `&` means that we will run the command in background and when we use it we receive `[number of process in background] [PID]`. This is what I have done:

```
firefox & > firefoxFile
```

But when I open `firefoxFile`, I found it empty. I don't find `[number of process in forground] [PID]`.

Comment: `&` runs in background, not forground. You seem to be using words foreground and background interchangably.

Comment: I have just tidied your question, I now realise that my answer is wrong (does not answer your question). I will remove it.

Comment: Do you want to find out the PID, hide the message, or both?

Comment: i want to find the pid and the number of process in background ,the both redirected to a file which it is in that example firefoxFile

Comment: For what it's worth ... i found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/620657/43458) that captures the PID (not the full text of stdout), which was all i really need for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell is bash[1], you can try:

```
exec 3>&2 2>firefoxFile; firefox & exec 2>&3-
```

It's your shell (eg. bash) which prints that `[jobnum] pid` background job notification to *stderr*, not firefox. This kludge temporarily redirects the stderr to the `firefoxFile` file, capturing into it that notification *and* whatever firefox will write to stderr during its lifetime.

It will NOT capture the `[jobnum] Done  firefox` bash will print when the background job has terminated.

---

Your `firefox & > file` will be parsed as two commands **1.** `firefox &` (which will run `firefox` in the background) and **2.** `> file` (which will truncate `file` without writing anything to it). That's most certainly not what you intended.

[1] you can read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475396/308316) why this trick doesn't work in other shells; while it's possible to redirect the stderr in `zsh`, `zsh` does not write its prompts and job notifications to stderr, but to another fd pointing to the current terminal, opened especially for this purpose.

Comment: i try ```exec 3>&2 2>firefoxFile; firefox & exec 2>&3-``` and it works ,thank you so much, when we use exec the output of command is written to file instead of my terminal ? and what's the role of 3> ? the commande is working but i didn't understand it clearly

Comment: When `exec` is used without any command, it just performs the redirections in the _current shell_. `exec 3>&2` saves the old fd 2 (stderr) into fd 3. `exec 2>&3-` is a shortcut for `exec 2>&3 3>&-` ie it first restore 2 (stderr) from fd 3 where it was saved, and then close fd 3.

Answer (score 3):

In your comments you write that

> I want to find the pid and the number of process in background

What about this

```
firefox &
pid=$!

echo "The PID for the background process is $pid" >&2
```

Having got the PID you can of course write its value to any file you choose.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact, but close. You will just have to add a bit of `sed`.

```
firefox &
jobs -l | grep -E "\[[0-9]+\]\+" > firefoxFile
```